# Improper spacing on achievements dialog on StackExchange

Tags: bug, design, stackexchange.com, achievements-dialog

Viewing the achievements dialog on [StackExchange.com](http://stackexchange.com), with many same-day events, causes tight spacing, as circled.

[image: badly spaced rep feed]

On other SE sites, it correctly displays like this:

[image: properly spaced rep feed]

Can this be fixed?

Comment: [Status-repro] <- It seems as if this only happens when looking from `stackexchange.com`